# Pycharm run PostgreSQL script: Cannot run program "psql ": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: pycharm, postgresql-9.3

Trying to execute SQL script in Pycharm using button "Execute SQL script" and get:

> Error executing SQL script
>   "/home/mike/PycharmProjects/db_pjct/DB/f_companies.sql".  Details:
>   Cannot run program "psql ": error=2, No such file or directory

DB Execution console:

> Jan 14, 2017 3:47:11 PM: shedule_db / f_companies.sql - Executing
>   command: psql  --echo-all --host=localhost --port=5432
>   --dbname=shedulator --username=postgres -f "/tmp/DBN763311781346405195.sql"

Database runs on localhost.
Statement execution in PyCahrm works well, no problem.
Execution script from console also works well:

> psql -h localhost -U postgres -d db_pjct -f
>   /home/mike/PycharmProjects/db_pjct/DB/f_companies.sql

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you found answer?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer

1. right click on selected text and right click "execute SQL Script"
2. A DB Navigator - Execute SQL script window opens up
   *open the drop down* in the [Cmd-Line interface] field and select "+"

2.1 -navigate to the psql folder (open a new terminal type in  "which psql" to find your installation dir"; mine is at '/usr/bin/psql' )

execute selected text to your hearts content :)

p.s. don't forget to press the commit button because everything you do is run in a transaction space, and you need to click on commit to see changes in the db,

Answer (score 0):

Personally, my table was created through the console when I clicked on the **"Commit"** button, and not on **"Run script"**